# Android Skydrive (LiveSdk) AssertionError (Unknown SkyDriveObject type) by clicking on Documents

Tags: android, onedrive, live-sdk

im using the LiveSdk Sample from https://github.com/liveservices/LiveSDK-for-Android.
I entered my ClientID in the config file, compiled and started the sample Application.
Now i getting:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Unknown SkyDriveObject type
```

if i sign in and try do open SkyDrive Documents. Mobile Uploads is accessed without any errors. Any ideas would be helpful. Thank you.

Here is the full trace:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(8872): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(8872): java.lang.AssertionError: Unknown SkyDriveObject type
E/AndroidRuntime(8872): at com.microsoft.live.sample.skydrive.SkyDriveObject.create(SkyDriveObject.java:75)
E/AndroidRuntime(8872): at com.microsoft.live.sample.skydrive.SkyDriveActivity$9.onComplete(SkyDriveActivity.java:746)
E/AndroidRuntime(8872): at com.microsoft.live.LiveConnectClient$OperationObserver.onComplete(LiveConnectClient.java:249)
E/AndroidRuntime(8872): at com.microsoft.live.LiveConnectClient$OperationObserver.onComplete(LiveConnectClient.java:1)
E/AndroidRuntime(8872): at com.microsoft.live.ApiRequestAsync$OnCompleteRunnable.run(ApiRequestAsync.java:46)
E/AndroidRuntime(8872): at com.microsoft.live.ApiRequestAsync.onPostExecute(ApiRequestAsync.java:166)
E/AndroidRuntime(8872): at com.microsoft.live.ApiRequestAsync.onPostExecute(ApiRequestAsync.java:1)
E/AndroidRuntime(8872): at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
E/AndroidRuntime(8872): at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
E/AndroidRuntime(8872): at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
E/AndroidRuntime(8872): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/AndroidRuntime(8872): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
E/AndroidRuntime(8872): at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
E/AndroidRuntime(8872): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(8872): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
E/AndroidRuntime(8872): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
E/AndroidRuntime(8872): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
E/AndroidRuntime(8872): at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: I got it too now, the SDK is outdated, I think they don't care too much about Android. The SDK is being a headache for me.